# Switch view from normal view to selected tab in TabBarController

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, cocoa-touch, uitabbarcontroller

I am developing an app which have a main screen with icons (as shown in image1) and when any of these icons is touched, the view will change to TabBar view.

what I am struggling on is switching to a specific tab in the TabBar view which match the icon in the main screen (image 1 and 2 will explain more hopefully)

[image]

[image]

As what you can see from the images, when I press on the icon with title "*item 3*", I want to view to change to the TabBar view at index 2 which is the 3rd tab

what I have done so far is I created an action method for the item 3 button and wrote the following code in it:

```
TB_ViewController *vc = [self.storyboardinstantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"HomeView"];
[self presentViewController:vc animated:YES completion:NULL];
[self.tabBarController setSelectedIndex:2];
```

I know it is not correct but this is all what I came out with, and I hope you guys can help me as always.

Comment: Please don't use the 'xcode' tag for questions which are unrelated to Xcode. Use the 'cocoa-touch' and/or 'ios' tags for general iOS programming questions.

Comment: try this: `[vc setSelectedIndex:2]`